# Generate hash key for android mobile app

Tags: android, facebook

I am working on a android app and has to provide the hashkey to facebook. I have tried 3 appoarch but none of them works.

By following the official doc:

1.) I write a command in windows like this

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\keytool.exe" -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\hk7.keystore | "C:\openssl\bin\openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | "C:\openssl\bin\openssl.exe" base64
```

output:

```
57GY9jCxTL9lwhI9oAsjNZN1UJ4=
```

2.) And the programatically way

```
try {
        PackageInfo info =     getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.package.mypackage",     PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            String sign=Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            Log.e("MY KEY HASH:", sign);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),sign,     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
}
```

output:

```
PH//aR6qmcnZxj/n+4oT6AzEMZQ=
```

Works but **only** for my device

3.) the alias value

```
keytool -alias hk7 -exportcert -keystore C:\hk7.keystore | "C:\openssl\bin\openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | "C:\openssl\bin\openssl.exe" base64
```

output:

```
kiHnmqD3oxggF1Y7rgTqaWTPZk4=
```

Only the second way works but it is only for my device . In my app , I log the exception , it said the API key does not match . but it seems each device has its own key. How to fix that?  and is it caused my openssl is too old? or the android side implementation problem? Are there any site for testing whether the key is work? Thanks for helping

Comment: The exception is only occur when I installed facebook app , it does not throw when I use webview (without facebook app installed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2nd way is t best one, Now you need to add every device hashkey  on which you want to test as your app is not on playstore .. once you upload t app on playstore/sign with a perticular keystore then you have to add only that keyhash.... Use this function to get KEYHASH

```
private void printKeyHashForThisDevice() {
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.package", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());

            String keyHash = Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            Logger.logger("============================================");
            Logger.logger("KeyHash================  ", keyHash);
            Logger.logger("============================================");
            System.out.println("KeyHash================  " + keyHash);

        }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: If I have to test the app in many device , what should I do? Also, I have set the app to public.

Comment: Create a signed installer with  keystore and generate hashkey for that sighned installer and pass this installer to youer testers/customers.. dont forget to add this kehash to facebook

Comment: Thanks for reply! Would you mind explain briefly about "create a signed installer"? So far I only have experience in exporting an apk through eclipse , how to create something like that?

Comment: In Eclipse Right click project-Export signed application package  That will take care of every thing.. Or just google how to sign apk